# A way to handle/merge 'successor records' in a large PostgreSQL table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a large table with 415,000+ rows that I need to manipulate in a very specific way:

- This was originally about people signing petitions online and their information being saved in a PostgreSQL DB.
- The original 'members' table had a very strange way of handling recurring signees: if a person signed a petition on the website, it would register their name (and other things, such as email address) and assign them a member_id (primary key). If the person then later signed another petition, but provided slightly different information, such as a misspelling of their name but with the same email, the DB would **create a new member** with a new member_id
- Eventually, a manual merge script would mark one of the two members as state='deleted' and assign it a 'successor_id' - the member_id of the other member that remained as state='active'
- Problem was: Other tables in the DB, such as the list of signees of a particular petition, still refer to the member_id of the old, now deleted, record. Normally, this would be solved by simply JOIN'ing the members table and using the successor_id field, but... Even worse, some members *have been merged 3, 4 or even 5 times*. Essentially meaning that a deleted member can have a successor_id, which has a successor_id, which has a successor_id... etc.

Now I need to export to a .csv all member_id's who have signed a particular petition and I need to resolve all these deleted members to their actual current member_id, regardless of whether it's 1 or 5 merged members down the chain.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? To create new columns called 'successor_id_2', 'successor_id_3', etc., and then only use the furthermost successor_id field that isn't blank? Or is there some other smart way to generate a list of all subsequent successor_id's of a particular member? I'm really at a loss here.

**UPDATE:** I've tried using a recursive query to essentially get a column of *canonical* id's (i.e. the id's of the one active member) doing this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE canonicalCTE AS (
 SELECT
 id,
name,
successor_id, canonical_id
 FROM
members

 UNION ALL

 SELECT
 members.id,
 members.name,
 members.successor_id,
 members.canonical_id
 FROM
 members
 JOIN canonicalCTE ON members.id = canonicalCTE.successor_id
) 
UPDATE members
SET canonical_id = m1.id
FROM canonicalCTE m0
LEFT JOIN canonicalCTE m1
ON m0.successor_id = m1.id;
```

but besides completely crashing my computer due to a lack of resources, I'm not sure it's the right way to find it? (It's still running)

Comment: What you have is *essentially* a linked list. What you *probably* want is: assigne a unique *canonical* id for every actual person. The natural choice for this is the lowest occuring for that person. You end up with a table {canonical_it, this_id} mapping the current id to the first one. This *could* be done by adding the canon_id to the original table, or by putting it in a separate mapping table. To populate it, you'll either have to iterate a few times, or use a recursive query to reach the first record for every person.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are trying to achieve. Can you please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statement for the `members` table and some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- \i tmp.sql

CREATE TABLE linkedlist
        ( id serial PRIMARY KEY
        , hops integer not null default 0
        , canon_id integer references linkedlist(id)
        , link_id integer  references linkedlist(id)
        , name text
        );

        -- create some data
INSERT INTO linkedlist(name)
SELECT'name'|| gs::text
FROM generate_series(1,101) gs;

-- SELECT * FROM linkedlist ORDER BY id;

        -- now:shake it up.
UPDATE linkedlist
SET link_id= id + 11
WHERE id <= 101-11
        ;

UPDATE linkedlist
SET link_id= id + 17
WHERE id <= 101-17
AND id % 7 = 0
        ;

        -- for the (recursive) self join, you *really* need these index(es)
CREATE INDEX ON linkedlist(link_id);
CREATE INDEX ON linkedlist(canon_id);
VACUUM ANALYZE linkedlist;
-- SELECT * FROM linkedlist ORDER BY id;
-- EXPLAIN  -- find the *final* successor for* any* id
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
        SELECT id AS this
        , id AS nxt
        , 0 AS hops
        FROM linkedlist l
        WHERE l.link_id IS NULL --final in chain (this is the canonical id)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT l.id AS this
                , t.nxt AS nxt
                , 1+t.hops AS hops
        FROM tree t
        JOIN linkedlist l ON l.link_id = t.this -- any id that points to the canonical one
        )
-- SELECT t.this ,t.hops ,t.nxt FROM tree t ORDER BY t.this, t.hops DESC ; \q

UPDATE linkedlist dst
SET canon_id = src.nxt
,  hops = src.hops
FROM tree src
WHERE dst.id=src.this
AND src.hops > 0
        ;

SELECT l.id, l.link_id, l.canon_id, l.name
        ,COALESCE(c.name,l.name) AS canon_name
FROM linkedlist l
LEFT JOIN linkedlist c ON c.id = l.canon_id
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Amazing! That was actually exactly what I was looking for! I appreciate the example code as well :-D

Comment: I ignored the boolean flags (Ithink they are redundant: the NULL links can carry the same information) But, you could of course add  some more conditions to the *logical skeleton*.